# cacert.pem location

Tags: ssl, certificate

Where can I find the 'cacert.pem' in Linux? I need it for ssl configuration.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, the CACert PEM is located in
**`/etc/ssl/certs/spi-cacert-2008.pem`**.

Not sure what your question is about, though.